# U-Sql view to merge duplicates via ranking

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have data lying in multiple files with naming convention as {year}/{month}/{date} which have duplicates (every day delta where records may get updated everyday).

I want to create a view that will return the records with the duplicates merged / squashed.
The duplicates will be ranked and only the latest updated records corresponding to each primary key will be returned.

But the use of rowsets in view seems to be not supported. Basically something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW viewname AS 

@sourcedata  = EXTRACT  //schema
from //filenamePattern (regex)
using Extractors.TSV()

@sourceData =  SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY primary_Key ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS RowNumber FROM @SourceData;

SELECT //schema
from @sourceData WHERE RowNumber == 1
```

So that when I do

`select * from viewname`

I get the merged data directly from the underlying files.  How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can be solved by table valued function. Have you tried using it?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/u-sql-functions

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have multiple `EXTRACT` statements in a view stacked together with a `UNION` statement which would *implicitly remove duplicates*.  However is there any particular reason you need to use a view?  This will limit your options as you will have to code within the limitations of views (eg they can't be parameterised).  You could also use table-valued function, stored procedure or just a plain old script.  This would give you many more options, especially if your de-duplication logic is complex.  A simple example:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS vw_removeDupes;

CREATE VIEW vw_removeDupes
    AS

EXTRACT someVal int
FROM "/input/input59a.txt"
USING Extractors.Tsv()

UNION

EXTRACT someVal int
FROM "/input/input59b.txt"
USING Extractors.Tsv();
```

Comment: I have made the question clear now, its not a simple remove duplicates ,  there is ranking involved  which keeps the latest updated record for each primary key.